# stationary vs. non-stationary GARCH process

Tags: variance, stationarity, garch

I estimated a GARCH(1,1) model and the sum of the ARCH paramter alpha and GARCH paramter beta equals 1.7. This points to an undefined *unconditional* variance and it follows that the *conditional* variance is a non-stationary and explosive process (Cuthbertson and Nitzsche, 2004).
However, Groenendijk et al. (1995) argue that the *conditional* variance process is still stationary, though not covariance-stationary.

Now, I am wondering what is meant by stationary. I assumed that stationarity (strict stationarity) implies covariance-stationarity (weak stationarity). And besides, which implications has a stationary *conditional* variance as opposed to a non-stationary *conditional* variance in this context?

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

References:

Cuthbertson, K. and Nitzsche, D. (2004). Quantitative Financial Economics:
Stocks, Bonds and Foreign Exchange. John Wiley & Sons, Ltd.

Groenendijk, P. A., Lucas, A. and de Vries, C. G. (1995). A note on the relation-
ship between GARCH and symmetric stable processes. Journal of Empirical Finance,
2 (3), 253–264.